# Why does my Mathematical Expression Evaluation function not work on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, function, expression

I've made a function in C++ to evaluate mathematical expressions. You pass the function a string, `20 + 10 * 3` for example, and the function returns a string which is the result of the expression that was provided. In this case, the function would return `50`.

The above function works with both OSX and Windows with the expression above. But when you provide an expression containing brackets it only works correctly on OSX.

For example, `(10 + 2) * 2` works on OSX, but on Windows it produces this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
```

Here's my function:

```
string evalExpression(string expr) {
    int res = 0;
    int getnextnum = 0;
    int iter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int temp_i;
    int i2;
    int temp_n_size;
    int ns;
    int second_eval_size;
    int bcount = 0;
    bool bstarted = 0;
    string b = "";
    string opp = "";
    string num = "";
    string num1 = "";
    string num2 = "";
    string ans = "";
    vector<string> numholder;
    vector<string> temp_numholder;

    if (numholder.size() != 0)
    numholder.clear();

    for (char & c : expr) {
        if (c == '0' or c == '1' or c == '2' or c == '3' or c == '4' or c == '5' or
        c == '6' or c == '7' or c == '8' or c == '9') {
            // c is a number
            num += c;

        } else if (c == '+' or c == '-' or c == '*' or c == '/') {
            // c is an operator
            numholder.push_back(num);
            if (c == '+') {
                opp = "+";
            }
            else if (c == '-') {
                opp = "-";
            }
            else if (c == '*') {
                opp = "*";
            }
            else if (c == '/') {
                opp = "/";
            }
            else if (c == '%') {
                opp = "%";
            }
            numholder.push_back(opp);
            num = "";
        }
        else if (c == ']') {
            // end of expression
            numholder.push_back(num);
        }
        else if (c == '(' or c == ')') {
            // c is a round bracket
            if (c == '(') {
                b = "(";
            }
            else {
                b = ")";
                numholder.push_back(num);
            }
            num = "";
            numholder.push_back(b);
        }
    }
    ns = numholder.size();

    STARTB:for (i = 0; i < ns; i++) {
        if (numholder[i] == "(") {
            temp_i = i;
            i2 = i;
        }
        if (numholder[i] == ")") {
            temp_i = i - temp_i;
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i < temp_i; i++) {
        temp_numholder.push_back(numholder[i2+i]);
    }
    temp_n_size = temp_numholder.size();
    for (i = 0; i < temp_n_size;i++) {
        if (temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-1] == "/") {
            ans = to_string(stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2]) / stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i]));
            temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2] = ans;
            temp_numholder.erase(temp_numholder.begin()+temp_n_size-i-1);
            temp_numholder.erase(temp_numholder.begin()+temp_n_size-i-1);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < temp_n_size; i++) {
        if (temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-1] == "*") {
            ans = to_string(stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2]) * stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i]));
            temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-1] = ans;
            temp_numholder.erase(temp_numholder.begin()+temp_n_size-i);
            temp_numholder.erase(temp_numholder.begin()+temp_n_size-i-2);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < temp_n_size; i++) {
        if (temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-1] == "+") {
            //cout << ns-i-3 << endl;
            if (temp_n_size-i-3 >= 0) {
                if (temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-3] == "-") {
                    temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2] = to_string(stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2]) * -1);
                    temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-3] = "+";
                }
            }
            ans = to_string(stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2]) + stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i]));
            temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-1] = ans;
            temp_numholder.erase(temp_numholder.begin()+temp_n_size-i);
            temp_numholder.erase(temp_numholder.begin()+temp_n_size-i-2);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < temp_n_size; i++) {
        if (temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-1] == "-") {
            ans = to_string(stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2]) - stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i]));
            temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-1] = ans;
            temp_numholder.erase(temp_numholder.begin()+temp_n_size-i);
            temp_numholder.erase(temp_numholder.begin()+temp_n_size-i-2);
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= temp_i; i++) {
        numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+i2+1);
    }
    if (ans != "")
        numholder[i2] = to_string(stoi(ans));

    for (i = 0; i < numholder.size(); i++) {
        if (numholder[i] == "") {
            numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+i);
        }
    }

    if (temp_numholder.size() != 0) {
        temp_numholder.clear();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numholder.size();i++) {
        if (numholder[i] == "(" or numholder[i] == ")") {
            goto STARTB;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ns; i++) {
        if (numholder[ns-i-1] == "/") {
            ans = to_string(stof(numholder[ns-i-2]) / stof(numholder[ns-i]));
            numholder[ns-i-2] = ans;
            numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+ns-i-1);
            numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+ns-i-1);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ns; i++) {
        if (numholder[ns-i-1] == "*") {
            ans = to_string(stof(numholder[ns-i-2]) * stof(numholder[ns-i]));
            numholder[ns-i-1] = ans;
            numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+ns-i);
            numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+ns-i-2);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ns; i++) {
        if (numholder[ns-i-1] == "+") {
            //cout << ns-i-3 << endl;
            if (ns-i-3 >= 0) {
                if (numholder[ns-i-3] == "-") {
                    numholder[ns-i-2] = to_string(stof(numholder[ns-i-2]) * -1);
                    numholder[ns-i-3] = "+";
                }
            }
            ans = to_string(stof(numholder[ns-i-2]) + stof(numholder[ns-i]));
            numholder[ns-i-1] = ans;
            numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+ns-i);
            numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+ns-i-2);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ns; i++) {
        if (numholder[ns-i-1] == "-") {
            ans = to_string(stof(numholder[ns-i-2]) - stof(numholder[ns-i]));
            numholder[ns-i-1] = ans;
            numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+ns-i);
            numholder.erase(numholder.begin()+ns-i-2);
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ns;i++) {
        ans = numholder[ns-i-1];
    }

    expr = to_string(stoi(ans));

    return expr;
}
```

I appreciate that my function is messy and probably does everything incorrectly, but I would really appreciate if anyone could take a look to help me find out what's wrong.

Comment: Where does this exception get thrown? Find what argument is being passed and turn your code into a minimal example with that argument and that function call.

Comment: @chris As soon as the function executes the goto. Right at the bottom.

Comment: `goto` doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: @chris My bad. It says what(): stof

Comment: Which `stof`? Use a debugger and check where the crash is. Then determine the argument going into that `stof`.

Comment: Use the debugger before asking a question here.

Comment: @chris It's line 109 of the function. This line: ans = to_string(stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2]) + stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i]));

Comment: `but I would really appreciate if anyone could take a look to help me find out what's wrong.` As soon as you used `goto`, the number of competent persons on SO that would have looked at your code was reduced by at least 50%. Second, the issue is more than likely your indices are out of bounds. Stuff like this: `temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2]));` If `temp_n_size-i-2` is some wild number, then your program was lucky to work on OSX.

Comment: You should use `std::isdigit` instead of comparing to every digit.

Comment: Also, read up on the `switch` statement.  In C++, you can stack them up so that more than one *falls through* to the same set of statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm amazed this program works.  There are sections of code that I don't understand, for example:

```
STARTB:for (i = 0; i < ns; i++) {
    if (numholder[i] == "(") {
        temp_i = i;
        i2 = i;
    }
    if (numholder[i] == ")") {
        temp_i = i - temp_i;
    }
}
```

The variables `temp_i` and `i2` may be overwritten before the loop ends.
An example expression: (6 + (4 * 5)) * 2
If the `numholder` contains more than one open parenthesis.

More items from inspection:

**if/else/if ladders difficult to read**
In your program, you could make the code easier to read (in my opinion) by using the `switch` and `case` statements:

```
  switch (c)
  {
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
        // c is a number
        num += c;
        break;
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '+':
    case '-':
      // c is an operator
      numholder.push_back(num);
      std::string s(c);  // Simplified all nested if statements.
      numholder.push_back(s);
      break;
    // And so on.
```

**Repetitive code fragments**
Why are you copying multiple code fragments instead of using variables:

```
ans = to_string(stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2]) / stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i]));
```

Looks like you could create two variables of type `double` before you start evaluating the expression:

```
  double argument1 = 0.0;
  double argument2 = 0.0;
  argument1 = stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i-2]);
  argument2 = stof(temp_numholder[temp_n_size-i]);
  switch (operator)
  {
    case '*':
      ans = to_string(argument1 * argument2);
      break;
    case '/':
      ans = to_string(argument1 * argument2);
      break;
    case '+':
      ans = to_string(argument1 * argument2);
      break;
    case '-':
      ans = to_string(argument1 * argument2);
      break;
  }
```

**Use appropriate data structures**
Your program evaluates the expression the way I demonstrate math to elementary students: by erasing the complex expression and inserting the simplified and restarting the parsing / evaluation process.  Very, very slow.  Computers can do this much faster by using other data structures, such as *stacks* and *trees*.

Search StackOverflow and the web for "c++ expression evaluate" and hopefully there will be some simple and correct examples.